# Android VideoView plays 2 videos at the same time

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play a `videoview` on top of another video view. The first video view is paused, while the second is playing.  It appears to work but no second video appears on the screen (though I hear the audio and see the controls that would normally appear on top).  I am assuming this is some sort of order issue.  Any thoughts.  By the way, I have no problem displaying other views on top of the main video view and having the video fill the background.

Answer (score 3):

That won't work - the VideoView is special in the sense that it 'punches' a hole in the normal Views to allow direct access to the display pixels (or, in android terms, the 'Surface' - VideoView is a subclass of SurfaceView). You cannot layer two SurfaceViews on top of eachother - the first one that grabs the pixels (the Surface) will 'own' it. (see SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated() / surfaceDestroyed())

Other Views on top of a SurfaceView *do* work, because the framework will compose the display bits of normal Views on top of the Surface. It cannot do that with another VideoView (i.e. a SurfaceView) because there is nothing to compose.

Answer (score 1):

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

when videoView2 starts playing setvisibilty of videoView1 invisible.
then you can make it visible when you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thread` to control both video

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful at the moment, but I managed to get something similar to what you want...

I needed to nest a VideoView on top of a SurfaceView; as long as they don't overlap 100% it can work. (what i mean is, my surfaceview is the whole screen and videoview is just a small portion of the screen)

The thing is - since you can't compose SurfaceViews, the first one to grab the pixels is the one that will be shown. Intuitiveness will drive you to Z-order your prioritized view AFTER the less-important one in the XML - but as I've said previously, the first one to grab the pixels stays, so make sure you define the smaller view FIRST, and then overlay it with the bigger one.

This will result in such behaviour that the smaller (in my case preview view) acquires the said X * Y pixels, and then the 'background' surfaceview (which is supposed to be on top of it according to the XML) takes up the rest and ignores the smaller surface.

I'm not too sure about handling events from those two though as I only have to play streams in those two views and not react to any kind of clicks/events generated by those two components, but it might be expected that if you followed this route - the bigger view will intercept all clicks made in the smaller view area (because it's on top according to the XML) so maybe you have to programatically move it on top as well upon creation.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
Although... it like it just works once. It's a work in progress really. Upon returning from any activity, there's nothing i can do to prevent the bigger view claiming everything :/

Answer (score 0):

you can  add videoview a on top videoview b,like this,

```
     parentview.removeview(a);
    parentview.removviewe(b);
    parentview.addview(a);
    parentview.addview(b);
parentview.invalidate();
```

Ti's work for me. I hope it can helps.