# can we play two videos sharing same screen in android 2.2?

Tags: android

i am creating application playing two videos,Its working fine on eclair,But showing error on froyo.
On emulator 2.2 its also working.

Comment: This is unclear. Can you provide an example of what you are doing presently? And of what you see on froyo and eclair? Do you see an exception? a blank screen? What code are you running, and what Android methods are you calling?

Comment: @Mohit Chauhan: can u pls tell me hot u playing two video simultaneously....is it possible?

Comment: @shubh 1st this will not work on 1.5 and 1.6 u can see  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937924/android-videoview-plays-2-videos-at-the-same-time/5153991#5153991 but i have tested on android 2.1 and 2.2 it works except on galaxy s